# How to retrieve a parameter from ajax to laravel API Controller

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, laravel

I have an API that requires a string parameter. I want to take the query parameter to the controller and process there. I tried `$ajax_data = Input::get('query')`; but it didnt work. Searched the same question but cant find a decent answer. **Current error is** $ajax_data **is empty**.

**My ajax request:**

```
const sendAPIRequest = function (csrf, f) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'api/apitest',
        method: 'get',
        data:{
            query:"select?facet=on&q=*:*&rows=1&json.facet={Categories:{type:terms,field:price,limit:3}}"
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tkid);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrf.trim());
        },
        success: function (data) {
            f(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
        }
    });
};
```

**My Controller API part:**

```
public function apitest(){
    $ajax_data = Input::get('query');
    $user_type = UserAuthorizationHelper::user_authorization();
    if ($user_type == Authorities::EDIT_ORGANISATIONS) {}
    $query = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    try {
        $response = $query->request('GET',SolrController::$url.$ajax_data);
    } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException $e) {}
    $data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    return response()->json(json_decode($data));
}
```

Comment: in your controller add this line to show all retrieve `info('parameter :'.print_r(Input::all(),true))`  @Arty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a problem in this line:

```
$ajax_data = Input::get('query');
```

When you are making a request, `Request` object is sent with the data.

So, instead of `Input` replace it with `Request`'s object, and you will get the desired output.

Something like this:

```
// Don't forget to import the Request's namespace
public function apitest(Request $request)
{
    $ajax_data = $request->get('query');

    // ... Rest of your code
}
```